# Class "Zend_Http_Client" not found Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2.4.6

I have few extensions which is using "Zend_Http_Client". It is working with Magento ver. 2.4.5. but in Magento 2.4.6, it says "Error: Class "Zend_Http_Client" not found".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As Zend usage deprecated since 2.4.6, Now you can use Laminas instead.

- Replace `Zend_Http_Client` with `\Laminas\Http\Request` (Replace constants from GET to `METHOD_GET`, POST to `METHOD_POST`)
- For example: `\Zend_Http_Client::POST` will be `\Laminas\Http\Request::METHOD_POST`  and `\Zend_Http_Client::GET` will be `\Laminas\Http\Request::METHOD_GET`
- Replace `Zend_Json` with `\Laminas\Json\Json`

Make sure that you have installed

- laminas/laminas-http
- laminas/laminas-serializer

More information can be found here:
https://developer-stage.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/backward-incompatible-changes/highlights/?utm_source=store&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=2023-02-magento-2-4-6

Answer (score 5):

You can resolve this (for the time being) by adding magento/zendframework1 back into your build.

```
composer require magento/zendframework1
```

Then do a full clean and it should all work again.

Comment: If I could give 1000 points right now I would. Thank you. I wonder why Magento didn't advertise this very easy workaround, than to wait the module developers to provide the adapted releases without Zend_* dependencies.

Comment: it is a good solution after it reaches it's EOL ?

Comment: Don't use deprecated framework. It's bad idea, guys

Answer (score 2):

Zend framework (ZF1) components that have reached end of life have been removed from the codebase. See [Backward-incompatible changes highlights](https://developer-stage.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/backward-incompatible-changes/highlights/).

Answer (score 1):

Zend has been replaced by Laminas. Be sure ton include
laminas/laminas-serializer in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

You need to install laminas/laminas-serializer via composer

```
composer require laminas/laminas-serializer
```

and then replace Zend classes with respective Laminas classes from your code inside vndor directory and app/code and all other occurences.

Follow this article for more details: https://meetanshi.com/blog/solved-class-zend-not-found-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

There are official docs with official suggestions (with examples):

**Zend_HTTP replaced with `laminas-http`**
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/backward-incompatible-changes/highlights/#zend_http-replaced-with-laminas-http

**Zend_Validate replaced with `laminas-validator`**
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/backward-incompatible-changes/highlights/#zend_validate-replaced-with-laminas-validator

**Replace `Zend_Http_Client` class:**
In your case you can use `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\LaminasClient` instead of  ancient `Zend_Http_Client`

Another idea:
Try to avoid direct usage of 3d-party classes like `Zend` or `Laminas`. In Magento we should use `Adapters` - as a Magento best practice