# Zend framework is deprecated in magento 2.4.6

Tags: module, extensions, zend-framework, app, laminas

I have just upgraded my Magento version from 2.4.0 to 2.4.6 and it is giving this error while opening admin. please suggest any solution

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): User Deprecated Functionality: Class is deprecated in /home/websites/hollywp/dev.domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/ZendClient.php on line 27
```

Comment: What steps did you take to upgrade?

Comment: Updated it through composer update command and  fixed deprecated errors but now stuck in this one

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/365716/50161

Answer (score 0):

For the solution, we can use LaminasClient class. **`Laminas\Http\Client`** class has the following method which replaces **`ZendClient`** class methods.

[image]

You can refer to more methods for **`LaminasClient`** class located at **`vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Client.php`**

You can refer this link for more infomation.
https://www.mage2developer.com/zendclient-class-is-deprecated-in-magento-version-2-4-6/

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: where to modify this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this (for the time being) by adding magento/zendframework1 back into your build.

```
composer require magento/zendframework1
```

Install zendframwork in your magento and it will work

[Reference link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/365565/90013)

Comment: I have to find a permanent solution for this!

Comment: @TishaJhanwar please add the solution here so that someone get help from that